# Need a book/series/online resource to learn college algebra to calculus

Tags: calculus, reference-request

I keep running into real world problems where I need to use math that I don't understand, but I know I need a good base to start with. I would really like a good series that goes from college algebra all the way up to calculus (and possibly even higher.) Are there any good recommendations? For consistencies sake I'd prefer a complete series. Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2):

Try [Khan Academy](http://www.khanacademy.org/).
It is a well known resource for learning.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have, and I love it! But I'd prefer to use it as a supplement to text.

Answer (score 2):

"Algebra by Israel M.Gelfand & Alexander Shen" is a great start I think, it is a great book on algebra, with some challenging problems and nice presentations, "Functions and Graphs - Izrailʹ Moiseevich Gelʹfand, Elena Georgievna Glagoleva & E.E. Shnol" is nice book as well to learn more about functions, and to learn trigonometry, I think that "Plane Trigonometry by S.L. Loney" is great resource, these are three books that I'm using at the moment and I think they are great, they're not big books so don't think that it'll take a lifetime to finish these 3 books to get to the calculus. For calculus I'm planing to use "Tomas' Calculus 12th Edition by George B. Thomas", I might reconsider but I would advice you to use it also because I read many reviews of it and of other books as well and I think Thomas' book looks great.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: use the following books 
1. "College Algebra" by Paliogiannis 
2." Precalculus" by Sullivan, 
and then any Calculus book from the many that exist.